# Jquery Custom Search box

Tags: jquery

I have created a new custom dialog box.

```
var dialog = $('<p>"Warning:"?</p>').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function() {

                },

                "Cancel":  function() {
                    dialog.dialog('close');
                }
            }

        });
```

i want to change the color of the buttons of the dialog box.
Any idea?

Comment: @Flex: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Use Chrome Dev Tools and inspect the elements.  Find the class names/IDs and use CSS to assign colors to those classes/IDs

Comment: Create CSS rules which target the buttons to override their background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the buttons by passing an object definition for the [buttons](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons)

You can assign a class to the button as given below, the use it to style the elements

```
var dialog = $('<p>"Warning:"?</p>').dialog({
    buttons: [{
        text: "Confirm",
        'class': 'confirm',
        click: function () {

        }
    }, {
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function () {
            dialog.dialog('close');
        }
    }]
});
```

then

```
.confirm.ui-state-default {
    color: red;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C3vPw/)

Comment: In the demo i can see a widget known as ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix.......is it possible to hide?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery creates elements on the DOM just like the it was created in some other way.

The items displayed have built in classes that can be manipulated with css. To prevent other Dialogs from having your change, I would recommend selecting the buttons and adding a custom class with your CSS.

Finding the data on the elements can be easily accomplished by installing Firebug (if you haven't already) and right click->inspect element with Firebug.

Good Luck.